# SQL Buddy Export to file "The file could not be opened"

Tags: sqlbuddy

I installed [SQL Buddy](http://sqlbuddy.com/) on my `localhost` and it has worked really well in place of `phpMyAdmin`, but the one thing I'm having issue with is when I need to export a database and choose to export as a file (`Output to: text file`), it is giving me an error `The file could not be opened.`

Has anyone encountered this problem/ know how to solve it? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have same issue and I solve it. You must have a folder named "exports" or "export" (read about this somewhere), I use the first one name. Create it in the folder sqlbuddy folder

```
/../sqlbuddy/calvinlough-sqlbuddy-1b38cf4/exports/
```

the path maybe different in your case, but the principle is the same.

After that you must give that folder 777 permission.

```
chmod -R 777 /../sqlbuddy/calvinlough-sqlbuddy-1b38cf4/exports/
```

Ok, done. Sqlbuddy now will export your sql base to a file.
This may be not a very secure, so I advise you to remove your .sql file from the server after every export. Hope it help you, as it help me.